# PowerShell: Get-Service w/ Get-Content, -name and select

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get the status of a specific service on 2008 R2 servers listed in a text file.

I once was able to successfully run the following:

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\scripts\Computers.txt"
Get-Service -ComputerName $servers -Name MrT | 
Select Name, MachineName, Status
```

As shown here: 
[image: screenshot]

Now when I run the same script I get the following error:

```
Get-Service : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At line:3 char:27
+ Get-Service -ComputerName $servers -Name MrT |
+                           ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Service], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Technically to get past this, I could run the following but would rather run against a list of servers.

```
Get-Service -ComputerName 3b, 4b, 7b  -Name MrT | Select Name, MachineName, Status
```

What am I doing wrong and how did it work once and not work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message points it out, the `$servers` variable probably doesn't contain any items. Check the output by running:

```
Get-Content "C:\scripts\Computers.txt"
```

Comment: When I run that I get a list of machines in the list. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What output do you get when you invoke `$servers.GetType()`

Comment: IsPublic: True 
IsSerial: True      
Name: True                                          
BaseType  System.Array

Comment: hmm, looks fine. Can you share the file?

Comment: Ok based on where you are going... I did some more troubleshooting and found the problem to be that some of the servers in the list do not have the service installed. I didn't think this would be a problem. I thought it would just not output like it does if I ran -ComputerName 3b, 4b, 7b

Comment: Ok I copied all the machine names and pasted them into excel then pasted it back in the txt file and now it works. =) Thank you for pointing out there was something funky with my text file.